# How do I access my control from another method

Tags: c#, class, variables, object, scope

I am making space invader and I want my bullets to come out of the position where my cannon is. When I press space a bullet will fire but I need it to be able to access the location of my cannonX every time I press space, it won't allow me to access its information.

```
    public void tsbtnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // Make invader

            Invader invaderX = new Invader();
            pnlBattleField.Controls.Add(invaderX);

        // Mke UFO

            Ufo ufoX = new Ufo();
            pnlBattleField.Controls.Add(ufoX);


        // Make cannon
            Cannon cannonX = new Cannon(this.pnlBattleField.Height - 80);

        if (made == false)
        {
            pnlBattleField.Controls.Add(cannonX);
            made = true;

        }
        Point location = cannonX.PointToScreen(Point.Empty);


        tmrClock.Interval = 200;
        tmrClock.Start();
        tmrClock2.Interval = 100;
        tmrClock2.Start();
    }

    public void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Space)
        {

            Bullet bulletX = new Bullet(this.pnlBattleField.Height - 80, location.x );
            // "location does not exist in current context

            pnlBattleField.Controls.Add(bulletX);
        }

    }
```

Comment: You need to get a reference to the `Cannon` object that's on the form, which is currently somewhere in `pnlBattleField.Controls`.

Comment: You need to reference the object; so you may access.  You'll also have to pass the coordinate values on the X and Y axis.

Comment: How do I reference the object?

Answer (score 0):

`location` and `cannonX` are local variables in `tsbtnStart_Click`, so they cease to exist once `tsbtnStart_Click` returns.  Make them properties of your class so that they will persist and become accessible in `Form1_KeyPress` and other methods.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Could you help me out with making them properties of my class. I asume I have to add them to my Cannon class?

I did something like this:

       public int location
        {
            get
            {
                return location;
            }
        }

I'm lost please help

Comment: Like @Sebastien posted, you'd add something like:
`private Point location;` to the class itself.  You can put this before or after your methods.
Then you can access the same `location` in both methods.

Answer (score 0):

Well , you declare

```
Point location = cannonX.PointToScreen(Point.Empty);
```

in your method :

```
public void tsbtnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

You need to declare this location in a class member at the beginning.
After that you'll overwrite his value with the correct value.

Like so :

```
private Point location = new Point();
location = cannonX.PointToScreen(Point.Empty); // in your method
```